# UV checkerbox looks strange when object is unwrapped

Tags: uv

Unrwapped and added basic seams, but when i apply the checkerboard texture it doesn't looks uniform. what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame you didnt screenshot the full screen so we can see whats plugged into that mapping node as it looks like its using "object" texture coordinates not "UV"

[image]